# How is it possible for an application to have static memory addresses?

Tags: memory-management, reverse-engineering, memory-editing

I'm using a memory editing application known as Cheat Engine. I attach Cheat Engine to a game. In my game, I have a 32-bit integer known as HP. HP is stored at a memory address A. If I restart my game, HP is stored at a new memory address B. It seems that using Cheat Engine, I can do a pointer scan and find a static memory address, C, that always stores HP's memory address during that session. So if I dereference C, I always get the memory address that stores HP. How is it always guaranteed for C to always be the same memory address? What if another application starts and occupies that region of memory?

Comment: I don't remember enough details to post a real answer, but I remember something about addressing memory relative to where the process is in memory. A pointer is not relative to the 0th byte in RAM, but from where the process starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what OS you are using, but most modern OSs use virtual memory for each process. The memory address for each program could be identical. The OS and computer map the virtual address to a real address in RAM.

Comment: Just in case it matters: I'm using Windows 8 64-bit.

Comment: Also, thanks for clearing that up. That makes more sense. Didn't know virtual memory existed.

Comment: The address of HP is relative to the beginning of the processes's virtual memory block.